# SQL query to get net profit stock wise

Tags: mysql, sql, database

| tid | stock | sid | sval | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 | 100 | buy |
| 2 | abc | 2 | 120 | buy |
| 3 | xyz | 3 | 300 | buy |
| 4 | abc | 4 | 240 | sell |
| 5 | xyz | 5 | 250 | sell |

Query to get the following output

**Output**

| stock | profit/loss |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 20 |
| xyz | -50 |

Another different Query to get the following output

**Output 2**

| stock | profit/loss |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 9.09% |
| xyz | -16.6% |

Explanation-
For stock abc: Total Invested = 220, Profit = 20, Percentage = (20/220)*100 = 9.09%

For stock xyz: Total Invested = 300, Profit = -50, Percentage = (-50/300)*100 = -16.6%

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to count "sell"s as profits and "buy"s as loses, and then sum them:

```sql
SELECT   stock, SUM(CASE type WHEN 'sell' THEN sval
                              WHEN 'buy'  THEN sval * -1
                    END) as "profit/loss"
FROM     stocks
GROUP BY stock
```

Comment: How to get these results in the percentage of total value invested per share. Like for abc it's 9.09% as (20/220)*100

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with 
pl as (select *, 
            case type when 'buy' then sval *-1
                      when 'sell' then sval  
                      end  as  profit_loss
            from sales),
sumpl as (select stock, sum(profit_loss) as sum_pl
          from pl
          group by stock),
sumbuy as (select stock,sum(sval) as sell
            from sales
            where type = 'buy'
            group by stock)
select sumpl.stock,sell,sum_pl, sum_pl/sell as rate,
 concat(round(rate*100,2),'%') as rate_percentage
from sumbuy
left join sumpl
on sumbuy.stock = sumpl.stock
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).